# how to run code with %run inside a string in databricks

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks

Hope all are doing well :D
I am trying to create a function with the path as a parameter.
Inside that function I would like to append that path to %run. And then run the notebook itself.

What did I do was:

```py
def another_func(path):
    nb = "%run" + str(path)
    return nb
```

This return the everything in between "". I tried eval(), exec() but nothing works, it does return the following error: "invalid syntax (, line 1)".
I also tried instead of "nb = "%run" + str(path)", %run $path but it doesn´t work as well :(
Thank you so much in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `%run`  is a special directive and doesn't allow right now to parametrize the path. You can pass `path` to `dbutils.notebook.run`, but it will execute that notebook as a separate job, not including the functions & variables into the context of the current notebook.

Answer (score 2):

I have tried same thing, but it worked

```
def another_func(path):
  nb = "%run" +  " " + str(path) 
  return nb
print(another_func("/sample/demo"))
```

[image: Below is the one which i tried]